# Voltage multiplier doesn't work

Tags: circuit-analysis, troubleshooting

[image]

I built this voltage multiplier today.

I hooked it up to my 10kV AC power supply and it worked just fine. It even lit up electronics from far away (from the EM waves generated.)

There was just so much coronal discharge and the capacitors were arcing so I decided to get olive oil to insulate it.

After doing this, the voltage multiplier stopped working and I don't have the faintest clue why.

Did the capacitors blow or did something else happen? Can someone help me out? I can provide more information if needed.

The capacitors are 20kV 470 picofarad and the diodes are rated 20kV as well.

Comment: Water content of olive oil is about 0.5%. Have you tried measuring the electrical resistance? Maybe use proper transformer oil.

Comment: *so I decided to get olive oil to insulate it.* What made you choose olive oil?

Comment: I watched a video and they said it had good insulating properties, does it not? I didn't have any transformer oil.

Comment: Remove it from the olive oil; does it still work?

Comment: probably the diodes a broken, if the arcing became.

Comment: The way you have wire points from the diodes poking out is bad at high voltage.

Comment: @HillmanSETYO no, it really does not have great isolating properties. What a sad waste of a great cooking oil! :( (Olive oil has other fantastic electrical properties, like exhibiting a high Kerr coefficient, but it's really a lousy dielectric for its polarity, acidity and water content)

Comment: @HillmanSETYO:  Is that 10kV peak to peak or RMS?  If it is RMS, then you probably killed your diodes and your capacitors.  You have to keep your eye on the peak to peak voltages.

Comment: To clarify things, even when removed from oil it doesn’t work. I’m thinking on using parrafin wax instead for my next multiplier, would that work? I think it’s 10kv rms. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: @import_hill: Check your diodes.  It is quite likely you destroyed them.

Comment: Please do be very careful and don't be shy about throwing a current limiter in the circuit somewhere.  Also be careful with those alligator clips as they are probably not intended for close to 10000 volts.

Answer (score 1):

Using non-passivated non-transformer oil < 1GOhm  will produce too much leakage. The capacitance will also resonate in the circuit with high reactive currents.

The surfaces of each part and the oil must be void of contaminants like fingerprints and moisture absorption into the oil.

Also the solder joints are too sharp thus increasing the e-field gradient and reducing the dielectric breakdown voltage.  This needs to be smooth. That's why they have round-insulated cicular conductors around UHV to reduce the gradient e-field and make it more linear.

You just need to use higher wattage, parallel diodes

Nice try though.